# Unable to iterate over dataset returned from an async function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, asynchronous, async-await

I am a JavaScript beginner.  have an async function, that has an await method in it, problem is that after obtaining the return value from that async function when I am passing it as a parameter to another function and iterating over it using a forEach it says data.ForEach is not a function

Here is my code

```
async function javed(){
  var map1 = new Map();

  map1 = await createMap();


  return map1;


 }

 function createMap(){

  var map2 = new Map();
  map2.set('11', true);
  map2.set('22', true);
  map2.set('33', false);
  map2.set('44', true);

  return map2;


 }

  let x = this.javed();
  this.Dome(x);



  function Dome(res){

    res.forEach(x =>{
      console.log('inside dome', x);

    })

  }
```

This shows the following error

﻿
Uncaught TypeError: res.forEach is not a function
at Dome (myfile.js:83:9)

Also I am not getting during the iteration how would I get the individual key and value if I want to manipulate or just console them?

Comment: `after obtaining the return value from that async function` Since it's an async function, the return value is a promise. You will need to `await` the promise to get the `Map`. The `await` inside `javed` won't cause code outside of `javed` to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value of an `async` function is a promise so you have to resolve it with `await` or `.then()`:

```js
async function javed(){

  var map1 = new Map();

  map1 = await createMap();


  return map1;


 }

 function createMap(){

  var map2 = new Map();
  map2.set('11', true);
  map2.set('22', true);
  map2.set('33', false);
  map2.set('44', true);

  return map2;


 }

  this.javed().then(x => this.Dome(x));
  
 
  (async()=>{

    const x = await this.javed();
    this.Dome(x);
  
  })();



  function Dome(res){

    res.forEach(x =>{
      console.log('inside dome', x);

    })

  }
```

A third option would be using only `await` in a top-level of a module:

```html
<script type="module">

async function javed(){

  var map1 = new Map();

  map1 = await createMap();


  return map1;


 }

 function createMap(){

  var map2 = new Map();
  map2.set('11', true);
  map2.set('22', true);
  map2.set('33', false);
  map2.set('44', true);

  return map2;


 }

 const x = await javed();
 Dome(x);



  function Dome(res){

    res.forEach(x =>{
      console.log('inside dome', x);

    })

  }

</script>
```

Comment: suppose the data returned from javed is to be taken  in a normal method (not async) means I cannot create a chain of await and async callers how would I handle that? What Im saying is if it is like  let x = this.javed( )  and then in the next line it is  this.passdata(x) how would I handle that in one go?

Comment: @Amax1 you can't do that, because `x` will be a promise, not a value of this fulfilled promise... you have the 3rd option, i'm adding to the answer

Comment: @Amax1 added, it's a top-level `await` in a module

Comment: @Amax1 i've upvoted your question, so you can now upvote my answer (the arrow up) for my effort of providing the module version, thanks!

Comment: Im little unclear by what you meant when you said await at top level of module. I dont see an await keyword before or after script tags. The script tags have module in them. Moreover I am not using Script tag as Im not using plain JS and HTML, Its a template concept as I am using Salesforce LWC

Comment: @Amax1 so use `await` inside `async` or `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that all `async` functions return a `Promise`.
So you're not calling `forEach()` on a `Map` as you would expect, but instead on a `Promise` which does not have that function.
Use `let x = await javed();` in order to resolve that promise and get back a `Map`.

Generally I would advise you to use the `this` keyword sparingly in JS, you don't need it at all in your example and it can often be something other that what you expect. Also, try not to use `var` anymore. `const` and `let` are much more isolated from external scripts and their scoping is easier to understand.

Here's a working example with the added `await`. If top-level `await` is not supported, you can wrap the behavior in a new `async function` as I have done here:

```js
async function javed() {
  var map1 = new Map();
  // createMap is not async, so no reason to await it
  map1 = await createMap();
  return map1;


}

function createMap() {
  var map2 = new Map();
  map2.set('11', true);
  map2.set('22', true);
  map2.set('33', false);
  map2.set('44', true);
  return map2;
}

async function doEverything() {
// you need to await javed
let x = await this.javed();
this.Dome(x);
}
// call the async function
doEverything();



function Dome(res) {

  res.forEach(x => {
    console.log('inside dome', x);

  })

}
```

EDIT: Yes, if you need a promise to resolve, you need to `await` it, requiring an `async function`.
The "old" way of using Promises (which `await` is actually just syntactic sugar for) does not require you to make the function `async`, but executes non-linearly. Here's an example:

```js
// I've cleaned up the code a bit, removing this and var

async function javed() {
  // the function is async, so it always returns a Promise. No await necessary.
  return createMap();
}

function createMap() {
  var map2 = new Map();
  map2.set('11', true);
  map2.set('22', true);
  map2.set('33', false);
  map2.set('44', true);
  return map2;
}

function Dome(res) {
  res.forEach(x => {
    console.log('inside dome', x);
  })
}


console.log("before javed");
// call javed, then Dome without a top level async function but the then method of a Promise:
// less verbose than javed().then(function(resolvedMap){Dome(resolvedMap)});
javed().then(Dome);
console.log("this will be executed before the callback function Dome!");
```

Comment: (assuming createMap was async) so then that means everytime I return a value from a async function (here from javed) , the caller needs to call it with await and it needs to have the async keyword too? But that will create a chain of Async await right? Because I checked and top level await was not supported. I use chrome. So I cannot have the data in a normal synchronous flow if I need it?

Comment: I get it. but if my javed function is returning the map value and this mapvalue I need to pass it to the Dome function which I cannot afford to wrap in an async as the rest of the code executes synchronously, should it be like this :  javed( ). then( x => Dome(x))

Comment: Yes. Or `javed().then(Dome);` or `javed().then(function(resolvedMap){Dome(resolvedMap)})`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying a `forEach` over a promise.
The method below is an async method, but it can return the value without `async/await` because `createMap` is not returning a promise.

```
async function javed(){
  var map1 = new Map();

  map1 = await createMap();


  return map1;

 }
```

OR

You need to use `.then` to get the value asynchronous like below

```
javed()
   .then(res => {
      Dome(res);
   });
```

Take a look on this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)